# Retrieve Image from Parse in Swift

Tags: swift, parse-platform

I am trying to retrieve a PFObject from Parse which has a class name (type) of Sticker, that has a property of type File called imageFile, that holds a .png image. I am then trying to set an existing UIImageView to have that image from parse as its UIImage.

Here is my code. Please scroll to the right to see my code comment:

```
import UIKit
import Parse

class DressingRoomViewController:   UIViewController,
                                    UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout,
                                    UICollectionViewDataSource {

    @IBOutlet weak var MirrorImageView: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var collectionView: UICollectionView!
    @IBOutlet weak var heightConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!
    let identifier = "cellIdentifier"
    let dataSource = DataSource()
    let layout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
    let cellSpacing: CGFloat = 2
    let cellsPerRow: CGFloat = 6
    let numberOfItems = 12

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        collectionView.dataSource = self



        var query = PFQuery(className:"Sticker")
        query.getObjectInBackgroundWithId("WGYIYs0crU") { 
            (sticker: PFObject?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
            if error == nil && sticker != nil {
                println(sticker)
                if let stickerImage = sticker!.objectForKey("imageFile") as? NSData { // it goes from this line, straight to the bottom of the function, without going into the if statement or even the else statement.
                    let file = PFFile(name:"resume.txt", data:stickerImage)




                    file.getDataInBackgroundWithBlock {
                        (imageData: NSData?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
                        if (error == nil) {
                            if let imageData = imageData {
                                let image = UIImage(data:imageData)
                                self.MirrorImageView.image = image
                            }
                        } else {
                            println(error)
                        }
                    }
                }
            } else {
                println(error)
            }
        }
    }
```

Why does the code not run past the code comment?

**EDIT: Just realised I didn't have an else statement for that if statement. I put one in, and it goes into the else statement. How do I get execution to go into the if statement?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it's skipping the `if` block, `sticker!.objectForKey("imageFile") as? NSData` must be `nil`. It might be nil for a few possible reasons. First, make sure your Sticker class actually has an "imageFile" property. Second, make sure object `"WGYIYs0crU"` actually has data saved in that property. You can easily check those things by logging into the parse web console.

However, I suspect the problem is that you are trying to downcast to `NSData`. Files are usually saved on Parse as `PFFile`, so try casting to `PFFile`, and skip the line where you create a new `PFFile`. Something like this:

```
var query = PFQuery(className:"Sticker")

query.getObjectInBackgroundWithId("WGYIYs0crU") {
    (sticker: PFObject?, error: NSError?) -> Void in

    // Also, checking for nil isn't really necessary, since that's what if let does.
    if let stickerImage = sticker?["imageFile"] as? PFFile {
        file.getDataInBackgroundWithBlock {
            (imageData: NSData?, error: NSError?) -> Void in

            if let imageData = imageData {
                let image = UIImage(data:imageData)
                self.MirrorImageView.image = image
            }

            if let downloadError = error {
                println(downloadError.localizedDescription)
            }
        }
    }

    if let imageError = error {
        println(imageError.localizedDescription)
    }
}
```

Hope that helps.